# Is Salesforce Schedule Interface Apex Time is using Fiscal Calendar

Tags: scheduled-job

I know that we can schedule apex using the interface below.
[image]

I am assuming that the 1 day of every month is referring on standard date not organization fiscal calendar.So I always make sure my code is retrieve the fiscal calendar.But I need to clarify that my assumption is correct, for schedule interface is it support fiscal calendar or not.For my case, the first day on every month might not fall on 1st , it might fall on 29 in previous month.

Answer (score 2):

That interface is an easy way to build up the Cron expression used by the [`System.schedule`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_schedule) method. It doesn't take into account the fiscal calendar.

There are more details in [Using the System.Schedule Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm#d33782e347-d34186e113).

> The `System.Schedule` method uses the user's timezone for the basis of all schedules.

Comment: Thank you.For all this time whenever the requirement is related to Fiscal Calendar , I will make sure that I will handle it my code and schedule the job to daily.Until one day I found my colleague schedule it to monthly so  I need to clarify this before anyone else simply using schedule interface with mind that it will follow organization calendar.

Comment: Oh, first day in everymonth in scheduler really mean 1st day ?

Comment: With the Frequency set to Monthly in the UI then "On day _x_ of every month" corresponds to setting `Day_of_month` in the cron expression. It means exactly what it says. Run the class on that day of the month (based on the current user's timezone).